# SSIS load from Oracle DB via MS Oracle source Attunity: Failed to load OCI method. OCIAttrSet

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I am trying to resolve an issue with unstable ETL process: Transformation of several tables from Oracle DB to MSSQL DB using Attunity source component.

The problem is that sometimes the SSIS package fails due to: **Failed to load OCI method. OCIAttrSet**. Rerun helps, but sometimes it is successful just after 10 reruns, sometimes it is successful after the first attempt. It seems to be very unpredictable and unstable which I do not like.

I was trying to set parameter **DelayValidation = TRUE** on the whole package and particular Data tasks, but it did not help.

One of my surmise is that the issue is caused by overloading the source DB and Oracle server is not able to send particular OCI methods.

Do you have any idea what it could be the problem and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I tried to use different OLE DB connection manager, especially **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle**.

I am currently having a new issue with collation. You can see below a preview of the data from Attunity connetion manager:
[image]

And here is the samee dataset, but via Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle.
[image]

In both cases I am using code page 1250, any case of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle I have to set: "AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage" = True, nevertheless it does not solve the problem with special characters.

Comment: I'm sure your Oracle DBA could tell you if the DB was overloaded. Somehow I doubt it (well an Oracle DBA would never admit that anyway). These intermittent errors are very tricky to solve. All I can suggest is either try and isolate the table or row or circumstance that's causing the issue _or_ just try Oracle's native drivers. I think it's more likely it's a client issue than a database issue. Or something in the database causing a client issue

Comment: I agree with Nick. It does look like a client issue. We have had lot of trouble with Attunity connectors. Sometimes they work and sometimes they just fail with unknown errors. It's pretty random. So we just removed them all and used 'Oracle Provider for OLE DB'. A highly reliable one.

Comment: It may be worth looking at the host usage.  I recently hit odd errors when the SSIS process tries to consume more RAM than the host had - this was due to configuration parameters, particularly if you have SSIS, SSAS and SQL all on the same server

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments. I tried to use different Oracle connection manager, nevertheless I am currently having a new issue with collation. See the updated post.